# How to edit a single character in a register stored string?

Tags: assembly, mips32

I am currently trying to write a function that takes a string argument, then removes any newline characters `'\n'` from it and replaces it with a terminating character `'\0'`. here is the code of my function so far:

```
removeNewLineChar:

strLoop:
lb  t0, (a0)

beq t0, '\n', changeChar
beqz    t0, exitRemoveNewLineChar

add a0, a0, 1

b   strLoop

changeChar:
lb  t1, '\0'
sb  t1, 0(t0)

exitRemoveNewLineChar:

jr  ra
```

I keep getting an exception on the line write under the changeChar label. Any reason why it would be throwing an address out of range exception? Thanks!

EDIT: If it helps the string in register a0 is: "This is a test string.\n" and it is being stored as .asciiz.

Comment: When you execute `sb  t1, 0(t0)`, what's in t0?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd at the top of the loop under the strLoop: label I have the current character stored there.

Comment: Right.  So, if t0 is "the current character," then what's a0?

Comment: Or to look at it another way, what would `sb  t1, 0('\n')` mean (since that's what's in t0)?

Comment: Did you mean `li $t1, '\0'`?   `lb` is using `'\0'` as an address.  (And BTW `'\0'` is integer zero, so you can just `sb $zero, 0($t0)`.